# Flutter limit write operations to firestore

Tags: flutter

Am trying to limit the number of uploads a user can make to the database. To this I have a function that uses streambuilder to check the database if the number of files are greater than 5, if so its supposed to return a dialog. else its supposed to allow upload. However this is not working, when I tap the upload button nothing happens and no errors are highlighted. Here is my code for reference

```
    Stream stream;
    
    startstream(){
        setState(() {
          skillstream=FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('posts')
              .doc(userid)
              .collection("UserPosts")
              .snapshots();
    
        });}
    @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        startstream();
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
    checkskills()async{
        //check firestore for the number of  posts the user currently has active
    
       StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
           stream: stream,
       builder: (context, uploadcounter) {
         if (uploadcounter.data.docs.length > 5) {
           setState(() {
             showDialog(
                 context: context,
                 barrierDismissible: false,
                 builder:(BuildContext context){
                   return AlertDialog(
                     title: Text("Upload limit exceeded"),
                     content: SingleChildScrollView(
                       child: ListBody(children: [
                         Text("Limit Exceeded"),
                         Text("You already have 5 active posts. Delete some before posting more")
                       ],),
                     ),
                     actions: <Widget>[
                       TextButton(
                         child: Text('Close'),
                         onPressed: () {
                           Navigator.of(context).pop();
                         },
                       ),
                     ],
                   );
                 }
    
             );
    
           });
    
    
    
         }else{
           Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/upload');
           setState(() {
             _isOpened = !_isOpened;
           });
    
         }
       });}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

body: Container(child:FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Upload"),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: ()async {
                        await checkskills
                      },
                    ),))

}
```

Comment: I'd state the obvious probably, but to limit anything that user does on your DB you need a backend to communicate with it, not the client app on user device. So the user data will first go to the backend and only it will have the access and rights to manipulate the DB based on that input.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'return' before StreamBuilder, like this:

```
checkskills()async{

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: stream,
   builder: ///etc
```

Comment: Added the return statement but still it is not working, instead am getting D/SettingsInterface(14248):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0   printed everytime I tap the upload button

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in future who might want to achieve something similar. I went the get() route instead of streambuilder and got it to work. i.e

```
Future checkuploads()async{
    //check firestore for the number of  posts the user currently has active
   return FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('collecttionname')
       .doc(userid)
       .collection("othercollection")
   .get()
       .then((value) {
     var count = 0;
     count = value.docs.length;

if(count>=3){
//do something

}else{
//your upload function

}

//the call the above function where you need it


}
```